# Excel VBA ComboBox error

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I am trying to fill a comboxbox located in sheet "AAA" with data in Sheet "BBB"

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("BBB").Range("m2:m200")) + 1
Sheets("AAA").Shapes("Drop_Leg").Select
With Selection
    .ListFillRange = "='BBB'!n2:n" & x
End With
```

I am getting the error

> "Requested Shapes are locked for selection".

I have tried different approaches, but cannot get it to work. This used to be a dropbox, but I was asked to change it to a combo.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try without using `.select`? Like `Sheets("AAA").Shapes("Drop_Leg").ListFillRange = "='BBB'!n2:n" & x`. This can occur when the shape is not visible or something, then it obviously cannot be selected.

Comment: Yeap, I have tried. I get the error: Object doesn't support this property or method...

Comment: is it a Drop-Down (combo-box type user-form) ? or Active-X combo-box ?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what is the maximum value in M2:M200?  (It seems strange that you are using the maximum in that range to determine how many cells to use in the next column.  E.g. if the maximum in M2:M200 is 497, are you really wanting to use N2:N498 to populate the combobox?)

Comment: This should work without selecting if it is of type user-form and no ActiveX: `Sheets("AAA").Shapes("Drop_Leg").ControlFormat.ListFillRange = "='BBB'!n2:n" & x`

Comment: @ShaiRado Active-x

Comment: @YowE3K between 8 and 19, depends on a previous listbox.

Comment: @Peh Doesnt work error as your previous solution. I am guessing now that the proble is related with the question raised by Shai Rado

Comment: @PauloAlves no it is because you are using an ActiveX combobox and the code is for an user-form combobox. I would stay away from ActiveX if possible, due to compatibility issues. Try using a user-form combobox instead with that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below to populate your **Active-X** `Combo-Box`.

There's no need to use `Select` to populate the `Combo-Box`, it only slows down your code's run-time.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillCombo()

Dim x           As Long
Dim ComboRng    As Range

x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("BBB").Range("M2:M200")) + 1
Set ComboRng = Sheets("BBB").Range("N2:N" & x) '<-- set the Range

With Sheets("AAA").OLEObjects("Drop_Leg").Object
    .Clear ' clear before adding new values
    .List = ComboRng.Value ' populate the list with values from Column N
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. for the help, but still not there.Get the error: 
    "Unable to gget the OLEObjects property of the worksheet class"

The reason why I used the active X was because the form comboBox for some reason doesn't let me type.

Comment: @PauloAlves  you copied my entire code and which line did you get your error ?

Comment: With Sheets("AAA").OLEObjects("Drop_Leg").Object

Comment: @PauloAlves That means that there is no ActiveX combobox called `Drop_Leg` in sheet `AAA`. Check your sheet name and combobox name again.

Comment: Solved. restart excel and voilá! your code is working perfectly!! Thanks

Comment: @PauloAlves  you're welcome, please mark as "Answer" by clicking the gray check-mark next to my answer, it will turn green